# Passing Custom Object to Progress Changed method. C#

Tags: c#

I am very early stages of my C# venture so I apologise if this is a simple question. I have looked and looked on line for an answer but can't find anything.

Basically I am trying to pass a custom object to the progress changed method from the background worker thread so that I can update a few labels and a rich text box. I know that with the report progress method I can pass a int and an object. But when I do, it doesn't let me access it in the bw_progressChanged method.

Here are some snippets of my code --

**Bacgkround Worker**

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
     UserStateSettings user = new UserStateSettings();

     user.rtbText = "Text";

     worker.ReportProgress(0, user);         



     if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
     {
         e.Cancel = true;

     }
     else
     { .....}
 }
```

**UserStateSettings Class**

```
 public class UserStateSettings
 {
      string _rtbText;
      int _productsProcessed;

      public string rtbText
      {
          get
          {
            return _rtbText;
          }
          set
          {
            _rtbText = value;
          }
      }
```

**Bw_ProgressChanged** (I am trying to get the objects property rtbtext into richtext box here, but it simply wont let me.)

```
 private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     this.richTextBox1.Text = ....

     this.Refresh();
 }
```

Hopefully this makes sense, if anyone could shed some light I would greatly appreciate it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to pull your object from the e.UserState property. You will need to cast it to your type to use it.

```
User user = e.UserState as User;
if (user != null) {
   // populate ui fields
}
```

See 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.progresschangedeventargs.userstate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what I needed, thanyou very much!!